# Can you create a 'Smart PDF' using Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad

I know on Altium that it is possible to generate a Smart PDF which generates a sort of bookmark for each component designator on a PCB layout, but unfortunately I have done my board design using Eagle 6.91.2 Lite Version and I not sure if it is a) possible or b) how to do it if it were possible.

I have the ability to print the design to a PDF but that doesn't work and even using the text recognition option on Adobe PDF Viewer doesn't prevail any useful results.

*<sub>Apologies if this is not the correct place to be asking such a question as it is about a piece of software. However as it is a schematic editor I thought it somewhat suitable.</sub>*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it out of the gate. You may have some luck finding a cam file that does what you need. Some quick googling turned up this:

http://www.eaglecentral.ca/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=31067&goto=107442&54b96c1ce9985e9d6fb9afcd2c81a408/